# Do we need to use sprites in cocos2dx as power of 2

Tags: android, ios, textures, cocos2d-x, texturepacker

I'm using texture packer for packing my textures. There is an option for export as actual size and POT.

Is there any problem in using NPOT textures in cocos2dx(consider iOS and Android platforms)?

Is there any advantage of using NPOT textures? Does it reduce the memory usage when it loaded into device memory.

Is there any advantage of using POT textures? Why most of them suggest to use POT?

Please help me to figure out these questions. I am using cocos2dx 2.x version.

Thanks,
Akhil

Comment: You can go through this
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/01/memory-calculating-size-textures-audio-buffers-classes-collections/

Comment: Anyone have suggestion for Android? I'm using cocos2dx, need to work on cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

Some (really "old") devices may not be able to load NPOT textures. On iOS that would be the original and 3G iPhones, I believe the 3GS was the first to support NPOT.

NPOT texture dimensions typically means less memory usage. On more recent devices they also don't suffer any performance penalties.

iOS once had a bug where NPOT textures increased memory usage by 33%, but that was way back when with iOS 4.x I believe.

I don't know the exact hardware situation on Android (I mean, who does?) but on iOS there's absolutely no reason *not* to use NPOT textures these days.